# Naive Bayes Identifying Neutrals PHP

Tags: php, sentiment-analysis

I am using Ian Barbers Naive Bayes analysis class to analyze the sentiment of sentences for a school project. I have created my own datasets of positive neutral and negatives. My problem is I have no clue on how to implement the neutrals and get the class to find them. The link below is for the php class I am using

http://phpir.com/bayesian-opinion-mining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the `Opinion` class is already pretty flexible for adding new "sentiment classes". Just the `classify` method has implemented the calculation of "prior" static. But it can be easily replaced with a `foreach`:

```
private $classes = array('pos', 'neg', 'neutr');
private $classTokCounts = array('pos' => 0, 'neg' => 0, 'neutr' => 0);
private $classDocCounts = array('pos' => 0, 'neg' => 0, 'neutr' => 0);
private $prior = array('pos' => 1.0/3.0, 'neg' => 1.0/3.0, 'neutr' => 1.0/3.0);

public function classify($document) {
    // remove those:
    //$this->prior['pos'] = $this->classDocCounts['pos'] / $this->docCount;
    //$this->prior['neg'] = $this->classDocCounts['neg'] / $this->docCount;
    // add this:
    foreach($this->classes as $class) {
        $this->prior[$class] = $this->classDocCounts[$class] / $this->docCount;
    }

    // the rest is fine
```